# How to upload an image to Firebase via a file path in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am generating images via an API call. The API call works successfully and I have been able to successfully download the image to the device. The next step I need is to upload this file into firebase via its file path.

Code:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:image_downloader/image_downloader.dart';
import 'package:image_downloader_web/image_downloader_web.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';

Future portraitsave(
  String? imageURL,
  String uid,
) async {
  try {
    // Saved with this method.
    var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(imageURL!);
    if (imageId == null) {
      return;
    }
    // Below is a method of obtaining saved image information.
    var fileName = await ImageDownloader.findName(imageId);
    String path = await ImageDownloader.findPath(imageId).toString();
    var size = await ImageDownloader.findByteSize(imageId);
    var mimeType = await ImageDownloader.findMimeType(imageId);
  } on PlatformException catch (error) {
    print(error);
  }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is use the "path" variable to upload this image into firebase. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention an image that you have in a local file, I'm gonna assume you want to upload them to Cloud Storage through Firebase and not to Firestore (which is a document database that is also part of Firestore).

To upload the local image to Firestore:

1. Create a `File` reference to the local file.
2. Create a `Reference` to where you want the file to end up in Cloud Storage.
3. Call `putFile` on the reference passing in the file.

Here's an example from the Firebase documentation on [uploading a file](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/flutter/upload-files#upload_from_a_file):

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
String filePath = '${appDocDir.absolute}/file-to-upload.png';
File file = File(filePath);

try {
  await mountainsRef.putFile(file);
} on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
  // ...
}
```